# How to create a JSON , RESTful service From main() method on server side in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat7

I created a java Project in which i am getting a JSON data from the main() method,. when i run it as a java application,
in which actually i am getting a data from a secured api with a key,.. so i want to create a RESTful service which will give the out put what ever i am getting the output of main() methods out,..
Actually i tried many Json Restful services but ,... None of them Used Main() method,.. Only problem is that i getting the data from main method,.. if i remove that main() method i won't work,..
Please help for any Json Restful service,. which will generate data from main() method to tomcat,...

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following changes helps you 
1)Rename your main method as getDataFromSecuredApi in a class SecureApiClass

```
public class SecureApiAccessor{
    public String getSecureApiData(){
        \\ your code in main method that gives the JSON api data
         return apiJSONData;
    }
}
```

2)Create servlet SecureApiServlet which calls SecureApiAccessor.getSecureApiData

```
public class SecureApiServlet extends HttpServlet
{      
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    SecureApiAccessor secureApiAccessor = new SecureApiAccessor ();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.append(secureApiAccessor.getSecureApiData());
    pw.flush();
    }
}
```

3)Create a servlet mapping for the servlet SecureApiServlet in your web.xml 
eg:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SecureApiServletProcessor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourClassHirchy.SecureApiServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SecureApiServletProcessor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getApiData</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

4)call the url eg:yourServerIP/getApiData from browser you can get the API data on the browser screen.